# A Core Data Fetch crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, ios6

I'm sharing a Core Data Controller class between versions of my apps.

The code works fine for an iPhone version but stops short on the iPad version.

Here's the code called from the RootVC:

```
    #pragma mark - NSFetchedResultsController

    - (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
         NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
        if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
            return _fetchedResultsController;
        }


         // Create the fetch request for the entity   
        NSLog(@"1");
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

 // Set up the fetched results controller

        NSLog(@"2");
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"3");

        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
       NSLog(@"4");
        // Set the batch size to a suitable number
        [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

        // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
        NSSortDescriptor *titleSortDesc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:titleSortDesc, nil];

        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

        // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate,
        // nil for section name key path means "no sections"
        NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController =
            [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                                  sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                           cacheName:nil];

        aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
        self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }
```

Log entry 1 shows. Log entry 2 doesn't show. I get this crash instead:

```
2012-11-19 08:37:26.402  I'm an iPad
2012-11-19 08:37:26.400  -[CoreDataController asyncLoadPersistentStores]
2012-11-19 08:37:26.403  -[CoreDataController loadiCloudStore:]
2012-11-19 08:37:26.404  moc is <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x1e03e4f0>
2012-11-19 08:37:26.421  -[CoreDataController iCloudStoreURL]
2012-11-19 08:37:26.454  -[CoreDataController folderForUbiquityToken:]
2012-11-19 08:37:26.460  -[RootViewController viewDidLoad]
2012-11-19 08:37:26.469   RVC moc is (null)
2012-11-19 08:37:26.470  -[RootViewController fetchedResultsController]
2012-11-19 08:37:26.472  1
2012-11-19 08:37:26.474  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'Person''
*** First throw call stack:
```

I'm passing the managed object context from the App Delegate to the RootVC like this:

```
rootViewController.managedObjectContext = self.coreDataController.mainThreadContext;
```

I could use some help figuring this out. I dont get whats different between the way it works for iPhone and OSX but not for iPad.. Same share data controller.

UPDATE:

These are the results from logs suggested in a comment by Phillip, below...

```
RVC is <RootViewController: 0x1f88d1a0>
-[CoreDataController loadiCloudStore:]
MOC is <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x1eda3630>
-[CoreDataController iCloudStoreURL]
-[RootViewController viewDidLoad]
-[CoreDataController folderForUbiquityToken:]
-[RootViewController fetchedResultsController]
1
SELF is <RootViewController: 0x1f8859d0>
```

Comment: At the point where you call `rootViewController.managedObjectContext = ...` can you log the value of `rootViewController`?  Also, the value of `self` at the point where you currently have `NSLog(@"1");`?

Comment: Thanks for helping Phillip.. I'm posting the results as part of the question...

Comment: So, somehow you have two different instances of `RootViewController` (different object addresses) where the one you're setting the moc into is not the one that's trying to use it to produce the `fetchedResultsController`.

Comment: hmm. i noticed that as I copied the log. I'll fine tooth comb it again.. I'll be back!

Comment: OK, so when I create the RVC in AppDelegate (it's a view from a SplitView), it gets a value of 0x1dd568d0. When it loads in ViewDidLoad, it has a value of 0x1dd4f3f0. This value is passed to the FetchResults array. I dont understand how this can happen.. Any ideas on where to look?

Comment: You say **"create"**.  Are you perhaps using code to `alloc` one RVC while loading a different one from a xib or storyboard?

Comment: I am using initWithNibName to start the view controllers from the AppDelegate. The nib names are not entered in the IB document.. I even built a replacement NIB (initially I just converted the iPhone version to iPad).. Still getting different controller ids.

Comment: OK. Got it.. I was recreating the split view controller, which in turn, messed up the rootVC. If you would put your first comment as an answer, I'd be glad to check it! Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments....

Logging the `rootViewController` address in the app delegate and the corresponding address of `self` within the controller's own method demonstrates that somehow you have two different instances of RootViewController (different object addresses) where the one you're setting the moc into is not the one that's trying to use it to produce the fetchedResultsController.

Comment: by the way, I learned something from your debugging technique. Thank you again.